# How to apply transform to only image in UIButton but not to title text

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cgaffinetransform

I have a Ubutton with a title and down arrow. On clicking the button, I open a menu and arrow should transform to the upside and when closing the menu the arrow should transform to the downside. When applying CGAffinetransform to ImageView in the UIbutton, the text is also transforming with some scale which I never applied. Button title changes when selected a menu item and the title will be centered to the view along with the arrow.

So, How can I apply the transformation to arrow only?Is there a way to apply or remove transform for title.

I had tried

`self.button.imageview.transform = self.button.imageview.transform.rotated(by: 180 * CGFloat(Double.pi/180))`

The arrow image on button should rotate based on menu open and close. That rotation has to happen in animation

Comment: make a custom view with text and image instead of button

Comment: Why do you want to use transformation? It would be much easier to use two different images with 'arrow right' & 'arrow down' and swap background image when button is tapped

Comment: Thanks @Lu_ , I want to use UIButton instead of customizing

Comment: @Olter, I don't want to use two images. I need to use one image and apply transform on it

Comment: if you don't want to customise it don't do any transformations, there is no other way

Comment: seems that's the way for smooth transitions. Thanks @Lu_ . Will be trying to work on that.

Comment: btn.imageView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)